# Real Time Collaboration API for iOS Apps

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I need a way to share a JSON data between 2 users in iOS and Swift. Does anyone have any suggestions for a way to do this? Maybe an official Apple or Swift API?

Requirements:

1. Easy to integrate with swift
2. Not hosted on a personal server

Thanks.

Comment: Use Firebase Firestore. That is Realtime, and serverless. See here for more info: https://firebase.google.com/products/firestore. It's developed by Google and has an easy to use API.

Answer (score 2):

Apple offer the [GroupActivities](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/GroupActivities) framework for that. During a Facetime call you can send custom data over the same connection for whiteboard apps with realtime collaboration. This year at WWDC 2022 they added a UDP tunnel for faster (but not guaranteed) data transfers and they also increased the packet size to 256KB. Here are some resources:

Videos:

- [WWDC21 session 10187: Build custom experiences with
  GroupActivities](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2021/10187/)
- [WWDC22: What's new in SharePlay](https://developer.apple.com/wwdc22/10140)

Sample code:

- [Drawing Content in a Group Session](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/groupactivities/drawing_content_in_a_group_session)
  Invite your friends to draw on a shared canvas while on a FaceTime call.

Comment: So I could only use this while the user is on a FaceTime call?